# Sorting Tabulated Data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, sorting, html-table

For example if I have a table with some [data](http://jsfiddle.net/zHRv4/) in it.

- What would be the best way to be able to sort this information via a date picker?
- How could I make this table accept information from an Ajax or JSON feed if required?

I have been given the following question hence my query regarding the question above:

**In HTML display a set of tabular data where the data contains dates.  Implement a date picker that filters the tabular data.  Where possible allow for the tabular data to be supplied via ajax or json feeds.**

Comment: Look into a plugin called table sorter: http://tablesorter.com/docs/ this is what you want. hope it helps!

Comment: I have managed to solve this question by the answer in this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867285/jquery-tablesorter-date-picker

Comment: saweet work! let me know if you need any hand! have a nice one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Tats_innit said in the comment you can use [tabsorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin to accomplish this. Using this plugin is easy, after loading the js files just use this

```
$('table.bordered').tablesorter({
    // include zeba widgets
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    sortList: [[0, 0], [2, 0]]
});
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/8cg4f/190/)

It detect date columns automatically and sort according to date orders.

You can check how can you append ajax fetched data into it here

http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html

Comment: Joy,  Could you implement a date picker with this?