# jQuery Tablesorter Date Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, tablesorter

How would I go about the implementation of a date picker into Tablesorter so that I can show a result between to dates `01/01/2001 - 01/01/2012`?

I have been given the following question hence my query regarding the question above:

**In HTML display a set of tabular data where the data contains dates.  Implement a date picker that filters the tabular data.  Where possible allow for the tabular data to be supplied via ajax or json feeds.**

Comment: Show us the relevant code please. Do you have a table with date fields and you want to filter the table rows based on the value of 2 datepicker inputs? Or what?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Here is my table http://jsfiddle.net/zHRv4/  I want to be able to filter the data between a certain time period.  I was recommended table sorter but there maybe other better options.

Comment: I'd just implement the jQuery UI `datepicker` plugin with 2 input boxes (min/max dates) and then, in a function called from either a `button`'s `click` or `onchange` of those `inputs`, get all of the `td`s containing dates in a selector and hide the parent (`tr`) of the tds with dates lower than the minimum or higher than the maximum date (don't forgetting to reset all of them to visible due to previous queries before executing this), but I guess the guys around here may have simpler ideas.

Comment: Thanks @FabrícioMatté I also need to be able to somehow implement a feature so that the data can be feed from a ajax or JSON feed if required,  Could you create me a fiddle as I am still confused

Comment: Datepicker and filter dates are very different things. It would save all considerable effort if you update question above with full behavior you are wanting

Comment: @charlietfl this is were my confusion starts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10860132/sorting-tabulated-data

Comment: You will either use a [`.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for JSON or [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) if you're `echo`ing pure-html table rows in your php/asp/etc to be fetched (note that the `table` element is read-only in IE, so you may have to replace the whole table if you want compatibility with IE). And yes, as @charlietfl, update the question with the expected behavior and some of your code, I'm sure you'll get useful input from other users as well. =]

Comment: @FabrícioMatté its just going to be plain html and hence why I am confused  stackoverflow.com/questions/10860132/sorting-tabulated-data

Comment: Again, one sentence posts with little detail don't help, you are getting confused partly because you are confusing others about the exact behavior you are needing..in detail!

Comment: @charlietfl Have updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I commented before, you can do this by simply using 2 [jQuery UI datepickers](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) - one for min date, another for max date - and filtering the dates.

I've made an extremely simple example, [Take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/zHRv4/20/). And [here's the commented version](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/zHRv4/21/) (you can also type the numbers in conjunction with the datepickers, which may prove to be an easier way around).

Now, if you want to load content dynamically inside of a div, you just have to take a look at the [jQuery's Ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or read some tutorials - that's pretty basic stuff.

The simplest way to make your Ajax would be wrapping your table inside a div, say, `tablewrapper` then you can use the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) jQuery method:

```
$('#tablewrapper').load('UrlWhichContainsMyTable.html');
```

In the example above you'd echo a whole `<table> ... </table>` (or have it inside a html document).

If you want to load table rows dynamically, you can use [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) methods to your table:

```
$.get('urlWithMyNewRows.html', function(r){ //or $.post, $.ajax etc
      $('table.bordered').append(r);
});
```

In the example above, you'd fetch a collection of table rows `<tr>` to append to your table from your `urlWithMyNewRows.html` document.

And take a look at [$.getJSON documentation and examples](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) if you need it. =]

ps. I call my fiddle "simple" as I didn't even validate if the `maxdate` is before the `mindate` to display an warning neither show a "No results found" message, even though those are just a couple lines of code as well.

Comment: Thanks,  Could you look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10868035/jquery-display-date-in-order-from-min-to-max